# MySQL query to get column based on dynamic data

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I get the value of "profit" to be returned by MySQL. totalCost and totalSell are obtained from the database.

```
select 
  sum(cost) as totalCost
  , sum(sell) as totalSell
  , (totalSell-totalCost) as profit 
from orders
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you try to directly count profit instead of using *aliases*?

Try this:

```
Select SUM(cost) AS totalCost
     , SUM(sell) AS totalSell
     , (SUM(sell) - SUM(cost)) AS profit
FROM orders
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f22ed/2)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use aliases in the `select` portion of the query that is declaring them:

```
select sum(cost) as totalCost, 
       sum(sell) as totalSell, 
       sum(sell) - sum(cost) as profit
from orders
```

If you wanted to do this using an alias (for some reason), you can do so when defining them in a subquery:

```
select *, totalCost - totalSell as profit
from ( select sum(cost) as totalCost, 
              sum(sell) as totalSell, 
       from orders ) t
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont perform, operations on aliases. You need to change `(totalSell-totalCost)`  to  `(sum(cost)-sum(sell))`

```
 Select sum(cost) as totalCost  , sum(sell) as totalSell, (sum(cost)-sum(sell)) as profit
     from orders
```